# What do you do when a supervisor gives you a task you don't understand?

Tags: work-experience

What do you do when a supervisor gives you a task you don't understand ?

This is always something I struggle with and would love to know the best way to approach it. No specific situation. I would like to hear what others have to say who have had this happen to them. Thanks!

Comment: "No specific situation" - Unfortunately, that makes this question too broad, and there can't be a real answer - just examples and opinions. Voting to close. But feel free to edit the question to be more specific and answerable.

Comment: John, welcome to Stack Exchange. This format is a bit different from what you might have experienced on other sites, such as discussion forums. The help center has a lot of guidance for you; I suggest reviewing [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to understand how you might be able to improve this question, or ask a better one.

Comment: @KentAnderson - no, this question is very easily answered - as there is really only one approach to take in situations like this.

Comment: @HorusKol - Even if the difference is slight, you'll have a different approach for different bosses. Even as you work with an individual boss over several years, your approaches will be different.

Comment: Well, OF COURSE, you ask. The interesting thing is HOW you ask, what do you do if you CAN'T ask and what are the consequences of asking or not asking. Amazingly, people on this site have recommended firing people for asking the wrong questions to their managers. It is not a simple issue-- but there needs to be more detail to this question.

Answer (score 4):

> What do you do when a supervisor gives you a task you don't understand
>   ?

As always, when someone asks you to do something, and you don't understand, you talk.

In this case you talk with your supervisor and indicate that you don't understand the task.

If you find that it's the task orders you don't understand, you ask the supervisor questions until you understand what is being asked of you.

If you find that you understand the orders, but you don't have the ability/understanding to complete the task itself, then you tell the supervisor that you don't have the knowledge to complete the task. You may be able to find time to learn how before the task must be completed. Or you may be able to work with someone else who can help enough to make up for your lack of knowledge. Or the task may need to be assigned elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I usually ask what is the end result that is wanted. Is it some code? Is it a Word document? Is it an Excel spreadsheet? Is it researching some technology? This can give me some idea of what I am supposed to be doing. I'd also ask what is the deadline and how long is this supposed to take. There can be various ways to get clues so I can figure out what was asked of me.

Comment: If you are afraid to ask your manager, ask who else in the department you should talk to for additional background.  Or ask your co-workers to point you in the right directions.

Comment: If you're afraid to ask your manager - you need a new manager...

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to remember - it is okay to not understand things, and it is okay to get help - a good manager or supervisor would rather you seek clarification before blundering on with a task and end up wasting time because you then need to fix the bits you missed because you didn't understand what was required.

As you go on through work, you will find that it will only be the most simple tasks that you will understand 100% upon being given the brief. The point is to then list which parts of the task (or tasks) that you don't understand, and send off for clarification to your supervisor (or client, or nominated senior team member).

If the request was clearly stated - "make me a combobulated widget", and the problem is you don't understand what is meant by "combobulated", then do a bit of research, and then send an email with the information you uncover and say "hey boss, I wasn't sure what you meant by combobulated, so I looked up a few things and wanted to check if this is what you wanted".

In the end, you and your supervisor need to be aware that information transfer during a task briefing is not 100% - the supervisor will make assumptions on what you know or what they think is obvious, and neglect to pass on that part of the puzzle. It's up to you identify the gaps in your knowledge and understanding of the task and seek clarification.

Comment: I concur with this opinion. I think what is important though is to never say you don't understand EVERYTHING. When you say you don't understand, do tell what you DO understand. Show that you took the time to try and understand the material but is stuck on some part of it. I would say most supervisor would expect you don't know everything but they would expect that you would attempt or figure out some subset of it before coming to them to figure it out.